# Ruby Soap datetime parsing error

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert a datetime that is returning back from a soap service which looks like this: "2011-09-30T11:25:56-05:00".

I want to parse it to this format "2011-09-30 11:25:56"

When I hard code the datestring in my ruby code, it works:

```
def parse_date(datestring)
    formattedDateTime = DateTime.strptime("2011-09-30T11:25:56-05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z")
    dt = formattedDateTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt
end
```

This example works when I hard code the datestring in.  However, the below example will not work.  The datestring that it is using is "2011-09-30T11:25:56-05:00", which is the exact same as I am hardcoding in the above example.

```
def parse_date(datestring)
    formattedDateTime = DateTime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z")
    dt = formattedDateTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt
end
```

This way it throws this error:
[01:29:06 PM 2011-10-09] SourceAdapter raised query exception: private method `sub!' called for #

Can anyone please let me know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I had to call to_s because the date that I was trying to parse was really not a string.

```
def parse_date(dateobject)

    tempdatestring = dateobject.to_s

    formattedDateTime = DateTime.strptime(tempdatestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    dt = formattedDateTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this problem. What is the scope surrounding this method call and definition?

Without more information, it's nearly impossible to tell what your problem is, but see guess below.

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > def parse_date(datestring)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003?>   formattedDateTime = DateTime.strptime("2011-09-30T11:25:56-05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z")
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004?>   dt = formattedDateTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005?>   
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 >   return dt
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007?> end
 => nil 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > parse_date nil
 => "2011-09-30 11:25:56" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > def parse_date(datestring)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010?>   formattedDateTime = DateTime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z")
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011?>   dt = formattedDateTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :012?>   
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :013 >   return dt
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014?> end
 => nil 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :015 > parse_date "2011-09-30T11:25:56-05:00"
 => "2011-09-30 11:25:56" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :016 >
```

**I would venture a guess, though. Try this..**

```
def parse_date (datestring)
  DateTime.parse(datestring).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end
```

Comment: [02:46:30 PM 2011-10-09] SourceAdapter raised query exception: invalid date

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I tried the DateTime.parse(datestring).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
and it did not work either.

The issue might have something to do with the PM times.  I tried to change my hard coded value to this "2011-10-04T18:43:34-05:00" and now it is giving me this error:
[02:46:30 PM 2011-10-09] SourceAdapter raised query exception: invalid date

Comment: I am looping through the results from a soap call and I want to change the date to another format.  My loop looks like this below.

requests = response.data.issues
    requests.each do |request|
      @result[request.xmlattr_issueId] =
      {
        'dateCreated' => parse_date(request.xmlattr_dateCreated),
      }
    end

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
Thanks for the help

Comment: I realized one mistake was that I was using "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z" an I which should of been an H since I am using 24-hour time.  However I still am getting the original error: [01:29:06 PM 2011-10-09] SourceAdapter raised query exception: private method `sub!' called for #